# SSIS - Is it possible to fetch Remote SSIS Package (Stored in SSISDB) From Local Server, And execute on the Local Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

We have an ETL-DB Server (SQL Server 2019) - installed with SSISDB and SSIS Service. As per our new company DBA policy, ETL Server will be treated as DB Server and no more allowed to install our Windows Service Applications on the ETL-DB Server.

To fix this issue, We got another SSIS Server(ETL-App Server) without SSISDB, only SSIS Service is running. As per our company policy this server is treated as non DB Server and we are allowed to install our Windows Services on this Server.

So, We installed our Windows Services on this ETLAppServer. Programatically these services are trying to fetch the SSIS Packages that are stored in SSISDB (ETL-DB Server) and Execute Locally in the ETLAppServer.

What I see, Local Packages can be executed from locally, Remote Packages  Execution can be triggered from  local server.
But the Remote Packages can't be fetched from a remote server and executed on the Local Server.

The Windows service uses `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices` and tries to fetch and execute the package using ETLDBServer Connection String.  But what we have observed, the package is executing only on the ETLDBServer,

Even though the Windows Service from ETLAppServer is the one trying to connect to the remote ETLDBServer to fetch the Package and Execute.

Note:
As per the below MSDN Document, What I understand, looks like it's possible. but I'm not sure of the Correct Solution.

[SSIS Remote Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/understanding-the-differences-between-local-and-remote-execution?view=sql-server-ver16)

> A package runs on the same computer as the program that launches it. Even when a program loads a package that is stored remotely on another server, the package runs on the local computer.

Comment: What you describe sounds pretty strange and on first glance I would say "no, it's not possible". Imagine a smart home: you remotley trigger the termostate at home - do you expect the temerature to rise in your home or in the location you are currently at? Same with the SSIS package: you can trigger the execution remotely, but the execution will start in the context of the remote server, not on your locan machine / server.

Comment: @Tyron78 But what I am trying, Is windows Servivce were able to fetch Package from Remote Server and Execute Locallay. I see in SSIS Framework there is "LoadFromSQLServer" or using ConnectionString.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Resolution have received from Microsoft Support.

> Project deployment is tightly coupled architecture. Packages in SSISDB will be executed on the same server where they are deployed.
> When you run the project in the project deployment model behind the scenes it will first trigger the store procedures in SSISDB which are responsible for executing.
> There is no way to make sure package execution happens on different server. You can install SQL server as well on your application server and deploy the SSIS packages to SSISDB